# How can I format my character code to a string name

Tags: vb.net, format, keycode

How can I format my character code (example: 13=enter) to a string format.

I tried using this method

```
(New KeysConverter).ConvertToString(13) '13 or Keys.Enter
```

But it formats characters such as whitespaces too, so that they look like "Space", and I only want the special characters such as CTRL or SHIFT formatted.

---

Let me try to clarify

```
Keys.A should become "a"
Keys.Space should become " "
Keys.PrintScreen should become "[PrintScreen]"
```

And I want a solution that works for all the keys that are like this, I *don't* want to check "manually" like so:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then...
```

---

I'm using Visual Basic Express Edition 2010

Comment: where are you doing this keydown or keypress?

Comment: I know this is about the same as your `If e.KeyCode =` solution you said you'd not want to do, but I would probably still go the way of loading in a dictionary with the ASCII val as the key and what I'd want to show as the value and then use that to output what I wanted...

Comment: @Plutonix My main form. On the KeyDown event.

Comment: I think the only answer will be to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
chr(13)
```

this will return a char, wich you can easly converto to string

```
Chr(13).tostring
```

or

```
Cstr(chr(13))
```

Comment: Surely, but all the special characters such as CTRL turn into weird characters.

Comment: of course they will, they have no a clear representation, waht you want to see?

Comment: That's the reason why I tried (New KeysConverter).ConvertToString(13) to begin with.

Comment: But what you want to do? I have write those codes in text files, then read them back and they work as I expected

Comment: Whitespaces turn into actual words, and semicolons as well (FOR EXAMPLE)

Comment: you are probably going to have to "record" all the special keys separately: `Ctl + A` to get what you want rather than trying to store it as one character or string.

Comment: the problem is that they are not whitespaces, they are characters, maybe you see the same maybe in control and shifth but your pc dont, thats the hard part, everukey will return a diferent character, so I think the only way is to do it manually

Comment: There's always Char.IsWhiteSpace(Chr(e.KeyCode)) but that still means I'd have to do it manually.

Comment: This answer reeks of VB6

Answer (score 0):

try `e.KeyCode.ToString`  It will not give you exactly what you want, for instance `e.KeyCode = Keys.A` will become `A` never "a".

And `e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen` will become "PrintScreen" without the brackets, and `Keys.Space` will become "Space".  Likewise "Enter" etc...

Comment: Yeah, I check wether the shift key is down and uppercase the character if it is.